# Online scheduling that takes varying transit times into account when offering scheduling options

Tags: scheduling, resource-management, travel

I'm a tutor, going from house to house. I work one-on-one with students. During the busy season, I can have up to 14 students. Most students see me at least once a week, but some only call me when they feel they need me.

I'd like to offer my students online scheduling, but I'm having trouble finding something that would work for me. I'd appreciate any suggestions you might have!

Many of my must-haves are standard in many online scheduling options. Confidentiality, allowing appointments for different amounts of time, real-time updating, and automatic reminders are part of almost every online scheduler I've seen.

What I need but can't find is online scheduling that offers different openings to each student, depending on how long it would take me to get to that student from the previous student.

For example, suppose I have three students: Clara, John, and Steven. Clara has already scheduled. It's 30 minutes from Clara to John, but 45 minutes from Clara to Steven. If Clara sees me 3:30--5:00, I'd like the online scheduling app to  automatically offer 5:30 pm to John, but 5:45 pm to Steven.

Maybe the online scheduling app could check Google maps for estimated travel times. It could then add an extra amount of time that I would specify and round up to the nearest 15 minutes. That way, I could allow for traffic, last-minute questions, etc. without being late or having extra transit time that I don't need. And people would get meeting times that are easy to remember (4:15, for example, is much easier for people to remember than 4:13 would be.)

I've seen online scheduling that lets me set a specific amount of time between appointments, but isn't really what I need.

Most of the features I'd like to see, but that aren't strictly necessary, are also standard in online scheduling. There's only one feature I haven't seen yet--the ability to hold times for 24 or 48 hours, without having a firm booking.

I'd like be able to put a temporary hold on specific times for specific students. That could be useful during the busy season, when everyone wants a Sunday time, but those times are booked. If someone cancels their usual Sunday time for a particular week, I could hold that new opening for a student who might want it. That student would then have 24 hours to confirm the time or let it go.

Of course, I understand that I'd pay for this service, and I'd be willing to pay a few hundred a month for it.

Comment: Great question. I can see this being a valuable tool for numerous service oriented industries. Tutors such as yourself, plumbers, electricians, traveling massage therapists, etc., etc., etc.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I've found that would meet the majority of your criteria would be [Housecall Pro](https://housecallpro.com/) a single user runs $49 per month billed annually.

Full disclosure:
I have no affiliation nor personal experience with this (although I've been considering it)

I'd love to see some alternatives as well.